# Converting MongoDB DateTime to IST format when saving in the DB using java Spring Boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, datetime

I have a spring boot application which I am using MongoDB as the database.I want to save date and time in **IST format** in MongoDB.

I have used these annotations in my model class.But this is not working.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");
@JsonFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",timezone = "IST")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@CreatedDate
private LocalDateTime createdDate = LocalDateTime.now(zoneId);
```

[image]

[image]

This is how it shows after saving it in MonogoDB compass community.And I want to show the same format as in Postman in MongoDB as well after saving.

Comment: The general recommendation is to store datetimes in UTC, at least for cross-timezone applications. Usage: IST is a *time zone* (or really some 4 different whole or half time zones), it’s not a format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@EnableMongoAuditing` ([reference here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/config/EnableMongoAuditing.html)).

Set `dateTimeProviderRef = "istDateTimeProvider"`

```
@Bean
public DateTimeProvider istDateTimeProvider() {
    return () -> new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
}
```

Comment: Should I put this in my model class or need to create a new configuration class and add this

Comment: you can add this in any configuration file or in main app also.

Comment: @EnableMongoAuditing I have already added to the Main class.And other thing I added to the configuration class. But it shows an error like Bad return type in lambda expression: GregorianCalendar cannot be converted to Optional<TemporalAccessor>

Comment: MongoDB by default stores the date and time in UTC format.But it shows the correct format in posman when again retrieving through the DB and it's fine.